# Flutter How to move file

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I will move certain files. how to move the image file from directory to another directory,
example file img.jpg from /storage/emulated/0/Myfolder to /storage/emulated/0/Urfolder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
await File('/storage/emulated/0/Myfolder').rename('/storage/emulated/0/Urfolder')
```

If the files are on different file systems you need to create a new destination file, read the source file and write the content into the destination file, then delete the source file.

Comment: what if only certain image files, example a.jpg file that I will move @Gunter

Comment: I have tried this:
Future moves Async image (image file) {
    var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory ();

    await File ('$ {dir.path} / Paska /' + '$ image'). rename ('/ storage / emulated / 0 / Uploaded /' + '$ image');
  }

but there is an error like this :

Comment: E/flutter ( 9504): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(186)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 9504): FileSystemException: Cannot rename file to '/storage/emulated/0/Terupload/File: '/storage/emulated/0/Paska/paska_of_201921560445.jpg'', path = '/storage/emulated/0/Paska/File: '/storage/emulated/0/Paska/paska_of_201921560445.jpg'' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: Future pindahGambar(File gambar) async {
    var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    await File('${dir.path}/Paska/$gambar').rename('${dir.path}/Terupload/');
  }

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(186)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (13995): FileSystemException: Cannot rename file to '/storage/emulated/0/Terupload/', path = '/storage/emulated/0/Paska/File: '/storage/emulated/0/Paska/paska_of_201921552811.jpg'' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: Sounds like either the source file or the destination directory does not exist.

Comment: already successful mr @Günter Zöchbauer, I entered the file variable incorrectly, it should be a path of file.. not file... btw thanks so much...
await File('/storage/emulated/0/Myfolder').rename('/storage/emulated/0/Urfolder')

Comment: It seems that `rename` may fail to OS Error: Cross-device link, errno = 18 for example when trying to move a file under folder `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/` to a new path under `/data/user/0/com.my.app/cache/`

Comment: Dart just calls out to system calls of the underlying OS and can't overrule on what the OS allows. So errors are to be expected if for example permissions are not sufficient.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I think `File.rename` should have documentation for these limitations (or better: fix it if possible). User of that API cannot know how it has been implemented.

Answer (score 50):

`File.rename` works only if source file and destination path are on the same file system, otherwise you will get a `FileSystemException` (*OS Error: Cross-device link, errno = 18*). Therefore it should be used for moving a file only if you are sure that the source file and the destination path are on the same file system.

For example when trying to move a file under the folder */storage/emulated/0/Android/data/* to a new path under the folder */data/user/0/com.my.app/cache/* will fail to `FileSystemException`.

Here is a small utility function for moving a file safely:

```
Future<File> moveFile(File sourceFile, String newPath) async {
  try {
    // prefer using rename as it is probably faster
    return await sourceFile.rename(newPath);
  } on FileSystemException catch (e) {
    // if rename fails, copy the source file and then delete it
    final newFile = await sourceFile.copy(newPath);
    await sourceFile.delete();
    return newFile;
  }
}
```